# How to set ZeroMQ subscribe channel in Mathematica?

Tags: apifunction, networking, socket

Mathematica 11.2 can do ZMQ socket programming now! But I cannot find out how to set subscribe channel from searching the doc. When using c language there is a function [`zsocket_set_subscribe`](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:espresso) to set the subscribe channel, it seems lacking corresponding function in Mathematica [Socket API](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketConnect.html) .

```
(* To create socket *)
client = SocketConnect[{"Pub IP", Pub Port}, "ZMQ_SUB"]

(* Then how to set channel to receive message? *)
```

---

I also ask in the [wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1188328) and will sync if there is an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think this part of the interface is broken. From some digging I found: `` ZeroMQLink`SocketOptions`Private`setSockOptSingle `` which is called by `SetOptions` on a [`SocketObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketObject.html). This makes use of `` ZeroMQLink`SocketOptions`$SetSocketOptionTypes `` to check the type of the argument and `` ZeroMQLink`SocketOptions`$SetSocketOptionValues `` to get the integer for what I'm assuming is the enum of the options.

I looked at `` ZeroMQLink`SocketOptions`$SetSocketOptionValues `` and found that `"ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE"` is supported, which we can get by `` ZeroMQLink`SocketOptions`toZMQOptionString@"Subscribe" ``. So in principle `"Subscribe"` should be supported.

Then looking at what the type should be we get:

```
ZeroMQLink`SocketOptions`$SetSocketOptionTypes[
 ZeroMQLink`SocketOptions`toZMQOptionString@"Subscribe"
 ]

ListQ[#1] && ByteArrayQ[ByteArray[#1]] &
```

Which basically tells us that we need to pass a list of integers. So then I tried:

```
pub = SocketOpen[Automatic, "ZMQ_PUB"];
sub = SocketConnect["tcp://localhost:8000", "ZMQ_SUB"];

SetOptions[sub, "Subscribe" -> Normal@BinarySerialize[First@pub]]

LibraryFunction::cfsa: Argument {55,58,83,36,99,99,50,101,51,54,102,98,45,53,48,51,98,45,52,98,53,97,45,56,99,55,50,45,55,101,101,53,49,56,99,48,51,55,54,50} at position 3 should be a machine-size integer.
```

And then digging more, we can patch this like so:

```
ZeroMQLink`Libraries`iSetZMQSocketOption[
   uuid_, option_?IntegerQ, val : {_?IntegerQ ..}
   ] :=
  Once[
    Quiet[
     LibraryFunctionLoad[FindLibrary["libzeromqlink"],
      "SetZMQSocketOption", {String, Integer, {Integer, 1}}, {Integer,
        1}], LibraryFunction::overload
     ]
    ][uuid, option, val];

SetOptions[sub, "Subscribe" -> Normal@BinarySerialize[First@pub]]
```

What this does I have no idea. Whether it does what you want I have no idea. But at least it throws no errors.

Comment: One can test by writing something to the publisher socket `Write[pub, "Hi there"]` and then check if the subscription socket has some message to read from by `SocketReadyQ@sub`. As it returns `False` I second your opinion that the interface is broken. Even if one starts `pub` and `sub` like this `pub = SocketOpen[{IPAddress["127.0.0.1"], 8000}, "ZMQ_PUB"];
sub = SocketConnect["tcp://localhost:8000", "ZMQ_SUB"];` it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/networking-and-system-operations/zeromq-publisher-model.html

```
pub = SocketOpen[Automatic, "ZMQ_PUB"]

subscribers = Table[SocketConnect[pub["DestinationPort"], "ZMQ_SUB"], 3]

Scan[SetOptions[#, "ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE" -> All] &, subscribers]

WriteString[pub, "Message from publisher socket."]

ByteArrayToString[SocketReadMessage[#]] & /@ subscribers
```

> {"Message from publisher socket.", "Message from publisher socket.", 
>   "Message from publisher socket."}

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late response. There is indeed a problem with ZMQ option management.

[@b3m2a1 did a very good job](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166965/23275) at digging into the code for an answer. The expected input is a list of integer (list of bytes to be more specific), but it's not WXF (this code predates WXF). It's actually the string bytes :
The following subscriber will only read messages starting with "ANIMALS":

```
pub = SocketOpen[Automatic, "ZMQ_PUB"]

sub = SocketConnect[pub["DestinationPort"], "ZMQ_SUB"]

SetOptions[sub, "ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE" -> ToCharacterCode["ANIMALS"]]
```

Now let's test this assumption:

```
WriteString[pub, "ANIMALS.CATS"];
SocketReadMessage[sub] // ByteArrayToString
```

Returns `"ANIMALS.CATS"`. Whereas:

```
WriteString[pub, "FRUIT.BANANA"];    
SocketReadyQ[sub]
```

Returns `False` indicating that there is no message to read.

I hope this (very late) response will still be useful. Be ensured that this part will be worked on so that it becomes much more user friendly, and duly documented.